# Union of two sets equals the entire space then it's a union of their closure and interior

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem proving the following:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A, B$ subsets of $X$. If $A \cup B = X$ then $\operatorname{cl}(A) \cup \operatorname{int}(B) =X$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are all boundary points of $B$ contained in the closure of $A$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! In order to get useful answers, it would be better if you could give us some context for your question : where does it come from? What have you tried to solve it? Where did you get stuck? You might also want to read the "How do I ask a good question?" page from our FAQ : https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, and take a look at the tour : https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I don't know where to begin, i got to the point that i need to prove all bounary ponts of  B are contained in the closure of B, i tried playing a bit with properties of sets but it didn't help.

Comment: If it was a metric space i would have looked at the accumulation points and maybe look at some series of points from the union

Comment: $$
X=\begin{array}{|c|}{\cdots\\A\\\cdots\\B\\\cdots}\end{array}
=\begin{array}{|c|}{\cdots\\A\\\cdots}\end{array}\bigcup\begin{array}{|c|}{\cdots\\B\\\cdots}\end{array} \\
\neq \boxed{\mathop{\rm cl}(A)}\bigcup\bbox[2px, border: 1px dashed black]{\mathop{\rm int}(B)} \\
= \begin{array}{|c|}{\overline{A}\\ \overline{B}\\\cdots}\end{array}
$$

Comment: Upvoted the answer.  Drawn a wrong picture.  I should have used solid lines for the boundary of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

If we can prove $X \setminus \operatorname {cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname {int}(B) $, the result will follow immediately. (Union both sides with $\operatorname {cl}(A) $.)

On the other hand, because of $X=A\cup B \subseteq\operatorname {cl}(A)\cup B$, we have $X\setminus\operatorname {cl}(A)\subseteq B $. As $X\setminus\operatorname {cl}(A) $ is open and contained in $B $, the required inclusion $X \setminus \operatorname {cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname {int}(B) $ directly follows.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x$ is in the boundary of $B$, then every open set containing $x$ contains a point not in $B$.  Since $A\cup B=X$, every point not in $B$ is in $A$.  Therefore, every open set containing $x$ has a point in $A$.  This, however, is exactly the definition that $x$ is in the closure of $A$.